# Javascript multiple setIntervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a scenario where i have one `setInterval` based code checking for value of an ajax call return. Like so:

```
var processInterval = setInterval(function () {

    var processResult = getVideoStatus(data.file_name);

    console.log(processResult);

    if (processResult === "ready") {

        clearInterval(processInterval);
        //Logic

    }

}, 1000);
```

As for the `getVideoStatus` function, here it is:

```
var getVideoStatus = function () {

    var result = null;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'someurl',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (response) {

            result = response;

        }
    });

    var statusTimeout = setInterval(function () {

        if (result != null) {

            clearInterval(statusTimeout);
            alert(result);
            return result;

        }

    }, 100);


}
```

What i tried to do in `getVideoStatus` function is for it to return value only when ajax call is completed and `result` is not null. I see that it does returns/alerts correct value but when i try to `console.log(processResult)`, it does not log anything at all.

I think it has something to do with first interval because the `getVideoStatus` seems to return value alright. Is there any logic issue?

Comment: You are using callback wrong. Do alert in callback, not in looped intervals.

Comment: `getVideoStatus` doesn't take any variables

Comment: Its all about asynchronous task my brother. getVideoStatus is asynchronous. Try to add `sync: true` in your ajax call and you will get your result but that is not the proper way. Learn to use the callback. i.e do everythiing you need to do after getting videos in the callback

Comment: Why you `return result;` in the interval?

Comment: @SumanLama I can't use sync, sort of pointless.

Comment: @hussain I know but you have written your programming expecting synchronous result. Any way sync: true is bad idea as I said above. Use promise or do your tasks inside the success callback of your ajax call

Comment: I have opted for deferred objects approach https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/ . Turns out i was doing it the hard way. But thanks for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you have chosen is not ideal to say less. Just use proper Promise/thenable API which is available for providing callback when data is available. In your case:

```
var getVideoStatus = function () {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'someurl',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html'
    });
}

getVideoStatus().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Benefits: cleaner and more predictable code behavior.

Comment: What if i use it with .when(), will it be better?

Comment: In this case you don't need when, as you only have one asyn operation you want to subscribe to. When is useful when you have several async objects.

Comment: Yes, i tested and looks like i don't need .when() afterall. Thank you sir. Since yours is the most compact and suitable working answer so i'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `getVideoStatus` does not return anything. So this code:

`var processResult = getVideoStatus(data.file_name);`

Is not working as you expect. There is a better way to do what you want. It is to use jQuery Deferreds like so:

```
var getVideoStatus = function(){
return jQuery.ajax({
    url : 'someurl',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    success : function (response) {

        result =  response;

    }
  });
}

var deferred = getVideoStatus(data.file_name);

deferred.then(
  function success(data) {
    // do something here, call came back w/ data
  },
  function error() {
    // handle error
  }
);
```

The thing you are not getting is that an AJAX request is asynchronous. The code will not continue running step by step -- instead, the browser will run the request and then come back and you can continue running but it won't be back in the same place that you started the request.

You can get something like that to work but nobody who uses jQuery would do that and it is complicated -- you need to use `setInterval` and check the ready state of the XHR request. jQuery does all that for you. So start with that and then go read how it works if you want to implement your own.